# Update AWS Lambda API Key Usage Plans with boto3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, boto3

I have an API Key associated with a particular usage plan. How do I use `boto3` to update the usage plan to another usage plan?

I've tried the following methods:

[update_api_key()](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/apigateway.html#APIGateway.Client.update_usage_plan) // add, remove and replace operations do not have usage plan path
[update_usage_plan()](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/apigateway.html#APIGateway.Client.update_usage_plan) // add, remove and replace operations do not have usage plan path

I thought about remove the key from the plan then re-adding but there are no usage plan paths.

Comment: The doc says: `Each op operation can have only one path associated with it`

Comment: I'm only using one path. My point is that none of the paths relate to the usage plan.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know if this is of any help but I run into a similar problem and I did find [this post](https://github.com/boto/boto3/issues/825#issuecomment-251234288) which did the trick for me!

So in my case I wanted to add a new Rest API Stage into an existing Usage Plan so the python script I used was:

```
import boto3

apigateway = boto3.client('apigateway')
response = apigateway.update_usage_plan(
                    usagePlanId='YOUR_USAGE_PLAN_ID_HERE', 
                    patchOperations=[
                        {
                           'op': 'add',
                           'path': '/apiStages',
                           'value': 'YOUR_REST_API_ID_HERE:v0'
                        }
                    ]
            )

print(response)
```

I hope this helps :)

Luismy

Comment: Thanks, for the link. It shed light on the format expected by 'value'.  In my case it was {'op': 'add', 'path': '/apiStages', 'value': '12l0qhemog:TEST'}

Answer (score 3):

You are looking for [create_usage_plan_key](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/apigateway.html#APIGateway.Client.create_usage_plan_key)

i.e.

```
response = client.create_usage_plan_key(
    usagePlanId='12345',
    keyId='[API_KEY_ID]',
    keyType='API_KEY'
)
```

Comment: `botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (ConflictException) when calling the CreateUsagePlanKey operation: Usage Plan XYZ cannot be added because API Key cannot reference multiple Usage Plans with the same API Stage: ABC:beta`

Comment: This call does not add new API Keys, it adds new associations between API Keys and Usage Plans. The error message you posted is unrelated. You can also use remove_usage_plan_key to remove the associations between API Keys and Usage Plans.